# How to refresh a cache when a certain file changes?

Tags: c#, file, caching, c#-4.0, updates

We have an app that's reading report requests and then it builds a custom query from a template file. Sometimes the template for a certain query can change and we have to update that template file and replace the existing file, or update the file in place.

The file is stored in a memory cache.

So, on file changes and we'd like to clear the cache and refresh it with the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use file stream and set the flag to write it directly to disk instead of caching

```
byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Eaxmple"
FileStream file=new FileStream("D:\\A.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None, 1024, FileOptions.WriteThrough);
file.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
file.Dispose();
```